# Openssl and pyopenssl return negative SN. Convert to positive?

Tags: python, certificate, biginteger, pyopenssl

I have problem when I get serial number from certificate over openssl and over pyopenssl. I get at some of certificates negative number but Windows gui or Unity GUI in ubuntu return positive serial number.
How can I convert negative serial number to positive? Or maybe better question How can get same value SN over pyoenssl or over openssl as in windows gui cert manager?

Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Examples that include code or commands would be helpful here.

Comment: Please post something like a [MCVE]. Hard to tell what is going wrong there, or even what kind of data you are talking about.